# Android --design a background service for fast data acquisition

Tags: android, architecture, software-design

I am developing an android app for our custom healthcare hardware device that, among other things, should receive data from 5 sensos. The sensor data are sent via Bluetooth and is received using delegates that fire at 64Hz, 1000Hz, 4Hz,4Hz, and 32Hz respectively. I have successfully created an app that received the sensor data. Unfortunately, at the moment, the sensor acquisition runs on the main UI thread. This is unacceptable because it is expected that the app should keep recording the data uninterrupted throughout the day. After spending some time exploring my options, many tutorial online suggest to use a service to achieve this. However, there are many types of services (IntentServices, foreground services, background services...) to choice from and I am not sure what is the best approach. Also, my app will target android O and it seems that using [background services are somehow discouraged](https://blog.klinkerapps.com/android-o-background-services/). Would any experienced android developer gives some suggestion on how to tackle this problem? Please note that, at the moment, this is just a demo and the battery and other resource usage is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach for things that you want to achieve is to use Foreground Service, that will keep connection with ble device and get notifications from gatt services. Also you will need to use WakeLock to keep your service alive in sleep mode.

One year ago was making [sample](https://github.com/HeyAlex/EarPlugApplication) app for internal ble device. Check [bluetooth/gatt](https://github.com/HeyAlex/EarPlugApplication/tree/master/app/src/main/java/app/earplug/com/earplugapp/bluetooth/gatt) package, was really useful such implementation.(project isn't good for production, but as sample/demo is pretty nice)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into int